# Firefox throws exception when setting `textContent` to undefined when webcomponent polyfill loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-component, polyfills

Our team is developing native V1 Web Components.

A fellow employee was getting an error, but only in Firefox, when running her tests for one component.

The error only happened when setting the value for `textContent` to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an initial test and it does not fail:

```js
    var el = document.querySelector('#outside');
    el.textContent = 'value';
    el.textContent = undefined;
```

```html
    <span id="outside"></span>
```

We scratched our heads and then she pointed out that this was failing in her Web Component.

So I loaded up the polyfill and added code to test a web component like this:

```js
    var el = document.querySelector('#outside');
    el.textContent = 'value';
    el.textContent = undefined;

    // Class for `<my-el>`
    class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = '<span id="inner"></span>';

        var el = this.querySelector('#inner');
        el.textContent = 'value';
        el.textContent = undefined;
      }
    }

    // Define our web component
    customElements.define('my-el', MyEl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.20/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<span id="outside"></span>
<my-el></my-el>
```

To my surprise the error occurred, not within the Web Component, but on the code that set the `.textContent` into the outer element.

So the existing polyfill for Web Components throws an error if you try to set `textContent` to `undefined`.

So protect your code by something like this:

```
el.textContent = newValue || '';
```

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the [following line](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom/blob/ab69f88581ce511ee7d6937446c0ed3a3e0e1a6e/src/patch-accessors.js#L257) in the Shadow DOM polyfill.

```
  if (text.length > 0 || this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }
```

in file *patch-accessors.js*: `text.length` can't work if `text` is set to `null`.

I've opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom/issues/203).

If you don't need Shadow DOM you can import only the polyfill without Shadow DOM:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.20/webcomponents-hi-ce.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid issue with ShadyDOM. I submitted the Pull Request which will fix the issue: https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom/pull/205

Setting `textContent` to `undefined` or `null` should not fail, but set `textContent` to the empty string:

[image]